# Check if substring is in array and spit it out

Tags: objective-c

I'm a Objective-C beginner and now I want to loop trough an array and check if the substring is in there. If true, the object of the array should be put in an other array which will be put on the screen. This is my code:

```
NSArray *origarray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                 @"One",
                 @"Two",
                 @"Three",
                 @"Four",
                 @"Five",nil];
for(NSString *words in origarray){
    NSMutableArray *newarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSRange range = [words rangeOfString:@"o"];
    if(range.location != NSNotFound){
        [newarray addObject:words];
    }
    textview.text = [newarray description];
}
```

In this case we should get an array of 'One', 'Two' and 'Four' because they both contain an 'o'. Unfortunately I get an empty array in my textview. (I know 'description' is only for debugging purposes). 
Is there someone who can tell me how to do this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NSPredicate` to do that, for example

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains %@", @"o"];
NSArray* newArray = [origarray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

or

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", @"o"];
NSArray* newArray = [origarray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

for case-insensitive matching

Comment: You may want to use @"SELF contains[c] %@" to make it case insensitive

Comment: Yeah, I thought he wants case sensitive matching, the example provided was case sensitive matching. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting an empty array is because every time you iterate, you are reallocating your array. Try this instead (notice i've put the allocation of the array before the loop so it's done once and also updating of the text view):

```
NSArray *origarray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
             @"One",
             @"Two",
             @"Three",
             @"Four",
             @"Five",nil];

NSMutableArray *newarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(NSString *words in origarray){
    NSRange range = [words rangeOfString:@"o"];
    if(range.location != NSNotFound){
        [newarray addObject:words];
    }
}

textview.text = [newarray description];
```

**Edit**: @Alladinian makes a excellent point that rangeOfString: does a case-sensitive search. If you want it to be case insensitive, you'd have to change:

```
NSRange range = [words rangeOfString:@"o"];
```

to

```
NSRange range = [words rangeOfString:@"o" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
```

Comment: That would be the problem. @yoeriboven -> Also I think that must be noted that `rangeOfString` does a case-sensitive search (so only 'Two' and 'Four' will be included)